Prove the formula for det(I + xA)
How do I show that the determinant and cofactors$(B_{kl})$ of matrix $B$ are given as follows?
$$
B=I+xA=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
 1+a_{11}x & a_{12}x & \cdots & a_{1n}x \\\\
 a_{21}x & 1+a_{22}x & \cdots & a_{2n}x \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{n1}x & a_{n2}x & \cdots & 1+a_{nn}x
\end{array}\right)
$$
$$
|B|=1+x\sum_{j}a_{jj}+\sum_{m=2}^{n}\frac{x^{m}}{m!}\sum_{j_{1},\ldots,j_{m}=1}^{n}\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{j_{1}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{1}j_{m}} \\\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j_{m}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{m}j_{m}}
\end{array}\right|
$$
$$
B_{kl(k\neq l)}=-a_{lk}x-\sum_{m=2}^{n-1}\frac{x^{m}}{(m-1)!}\sum_{j_{1},\ldots,j_{m-1}=1}^{n}\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{lk} & a_{lj_{1}} & \cdots & a_{lj_{m-1}} \\\\
 a_{j_{1}k} & a_{j_{1}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{1}j_{m-1}} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j_{m-1}k} & a_{j_{m-1}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{m-1}j_{m-1}}
\end{array}\right|
$$
After a long time of working out my own solution, I was able to post an Answer below. Please let me know if there is a better way.

Very nice.  Yes that is a good way to put my argument under your paradigm.

I was not aware of that. If I just repeat the same operation for each first-order differentiated term, the order of the values taken by $j_1$ to $j_m$ is not specified, but I can write the expression more concisely by specifying the order and multiplying by $m!$. However, this question doesn't seem to ask for that.

If the subscript of line number $j$ is the differentiated order of the lines, the magnitude relationship of $j$ is not specified. Therefore, in the expression $|B|$ in the question, the order of the lines is disordered. However, the order of the columns is also specified by the subscript $j$. If we change the order of the rows from magnitude order to subscript order, the same number of columns will be swapped, and the sign will remain unchanged.

You are right $(-1)^2=1$.  I just realised.  The question gives the correct formula which is the same as the one in my answer.

My approach is to use the Maclaurin expansion and compute the derivative of the determinant.
$$
|B|=\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{x^{m}}{m!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{m}|B|}{\mathrm{d}x^{m}}(x=0)
$$
The problem then becomes to show the following formula for the derivative.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{m}|B|}{\mathrm{d}x^{m}}(x=0)=\sum_{j_{1},\ldots,j_{m}=1}^{n}\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{j_{1}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{1}j_{m}} \\\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j_{m}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{m}j_{m}}
\end{array}\right|
$$
It can be verified as follows.

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}|B|}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)b_{1\sigma(1)}b_{2\sigma(2)}\cdots b_{n\sigma(n)}
$$
$$
=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)b_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots b_{(j-1)\sigma(j-1)}a_{j\sigma(j)}b_{(j+1)\sigma(j+1)}\cdots b_{n\sigma(n)}
$$
$$
=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
 \vdots & & \vdots \\\\
 b_{(j-1)1} & \cdots & b_{(j-1)n} \\\\
 a_{j1} & \cdots & a_{jn} \\\\
 b_{(j+1)1} & \cdots & b_{(j+1)n} \\\\
 \vdots & & \vdots
\end{array}\right|\xrightarrow{x\to0}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{jj}
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{m}|B|}{\mathrm{d}x^{m}}=\sum_{j_{1},\ldots,j_{m}}^{\text{No duplicates}}\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
 \vdots & & \vdots \\\\
 b_{(j_{2}-1)1} & \cdots & b_{(j_{2}-1)n} \\\\
 a_{j_{2}1} & \cdots & a_{j_{2}n} \\\\
 b_{(j_{2}+1)1} & \cdots & b_{(j_{2}+1)n} \\\\ 
 \vdots & & \vdots \\\\
 b_{(j_{1}-1)1} & \cdots & b_{(j_{1}-1)n} \\\\
 a_{j_{1}1} & \cdots & a_{j_{1}n} \\\\
 b_{(j_{1}+1)1} & \cdots & b_{(j_{1}+1)n} \\\\
 \vdots & & \vdots \\\\
 b_{(j_{m}-1)1} & \cdots & b_{(j_{m}-1)n} \\\\
 a_{j_{m}1} & \cdots & a_{j_{m}n} \\\\
 b_{(j_{m}+1)1} & \cdots & b_{(j_{m}+1)n} \\\\ 
 \vdots & & \vdots \\\\
\end{array}\right|
$$
$$
=\sum_{j_{1},\ldots,j_{m}}^{\text{No duplicates}}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)b_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots b_{(j_{2}-1)\sigma(j_{2}-1)}a_{j_{2}\sigma(j_{2})}b_{(j_{2}+1)\sigma(j_{2}+1)}\cdots b_{(j_{1}-1)\sigma(j_{1}-1)}a_{j_{1}\sigma(j_{1})}b_{(j_{1}+1)\sigma(j_{1}+1)}\cdots b_{(j_{m}-1)\sigma(j_{m}-1)}a_{j_{m}\sigma(j_{m})}b_{(j_{m}+1)\sigma(j_{m}+1)}\cdots b_{n\sigma(n)}
$$
$$
\xrightarrow{x\to0}\sum_{j_{1},\ldots,j_{m}}^{\text{No duplicates}}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{m}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)a_{j_{1}\sigma(j_{1})}\cdots a_{j_{m}\sigma(j_{m})}=\sum_{j_{1},\ldots,j_{m}}\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{j_{1}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{1}j_{m}} \\\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j_{m}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{m}j_{m}}
\end{array}\right|
$$
$$
\left(=m!\sum_{j_{1}<\ldots<j_{m}}\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{j_{1}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{1}j_{m}} \\\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j_{m}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{m}j_{m}}
\end{array}\right|\right)
$$

For the cofactors, I first calculated for $B_{21}$.
$$
B_{21}=-\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 b_{12} & b_{13} & \cdots & b_{1n} \\\\
 b_{32} & b_{33} & \cdots & b_{3n} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 b_{n2} & b_{n3} & \cdots & b_{nn}
\end{array}\right|=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^{m}}{m!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{m}B_{21}}{\mathrm{d}x^{m}}(x=0)
$$
$$
B_{21}(x=0)=0,\quad \frac{\mathrm{d}B_{21}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x=0)=-\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\\\
 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
\end{array}\right|-\sum\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & \cdots & 0 \\\\
 \vdots & & \vdots \\\\
\end{array}\right|=-a_{12}
$$
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}B_{21}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\\\
 b_{32} & b_{33} & \cdots & b_{3n} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
\end{array}\right|-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 b_{12} & b_{13} & \cdots & b_{1n} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j2} & a_{j3} & \ddots & a_{jn} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
\end{array}\right|
$$
$$
=-\sum_{j}\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\\\
 b_{32} & b_{33} & \cdots & b_{3n} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j2} & a_{j3} & \ddots & a_{jn} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
\end{array}\right|-\sum_{j}\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\\\
 b_{32} & b_{33} & \cdots & b_{3n} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j2} & a_{j3} & \ddots & a_{jn} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
\end{array}\right|
$$
$$
=-2\sum_{j}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{j\sigma(j)}b_{2\sigma(2)}\cdots
$$
$$
\xrightarrow{x\to0}-2\sum_{j}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{2}}\text{sgn}(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{j\sigma(j)}=-2\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{12} & a_{j2} \\\\
 a_{1j} & a_{jj} \\\\
\end{array}\right|
$$
Thus, since $B_{kl}$ loses the diagonal components of the $l$th column and $k$th row and $x\to0$, the $k$th column (not row) and $l$th row (not column) become zero, we need to differentiate the $l$th row somewhere in the middle of differentiating $m$ times to make the whole $l$th row $\boldsymbol{a}_{l}$. When $m$ rows containing the $l$th row are selected for differentiation, there are $m$ times to differentiate the $l$th row, so
$$
B_{kl}(x=0)=0,\quad
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{m}B_{kl}}{\mathrm{d}x^{m}}(x=0)=(-1)^{k+l}m\sum_{j_{1},\ldots,j_{m-1}}\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{lk} & a_{lj_{1}} & \cdots & a_{lj_{m-1}} \\\\
 a_{j_{1}k} & a_{j_{1}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{1}j_{m-1}} \\\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j_{m-1}k} & a_{j_{m-1}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{m-1}j_{m-1}}
\end{array}\right|
$$
Please let me know if there is a better way.

We have $$|1+Ax|=
\sum_{\sigma\in S_n} \epsilon_\sigma\prod_{i=1}^n (a_{i\sigma_i}x+\delta_{i\sigma_i})
$$
$$
=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k \sum_{j_1<\cdots<j_k\in1,\cdots,n} \quad \sum_{\sigma\in {\rm Stab}\left(\{j_i,\cdots,j_k)\}^C\right) }\epsilon_{\sigma}\prod_{i=1}^k a_{j_i\sigma_{j_i}}
$$
$$
=\sum_{k=0}^n x^k \sum_{j_1<\cdots<j_k\in1,\cdots,n} \quad \left|\begin{array}{cccc}
 a_{j_{1}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{1}j_{k}} \\\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\
 a_{j_{k}j_{1}} & \cdots & a_{j_{k}j_{k}}
\end{array}\right|
$$
Here the first and final equality are just the definition of determinant and minor.  $S_n$ denotes the set of permutations of the indices.  $\epsilon_\sigma$ is the sign of the permutation $\sigma$.  $\delta_{ij}$ is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.  Finally ${\rm Stab}\left(\{j_i,\cdots,j_k)\}^C\right)$ is the set of permutations of the indices which only move (some of) $j_1,\cdots,j_k$.  Note the sign of such a permutation is the same as the sign of its restriction to $j_1,\cdots,j_k$.
The key step was the middle equality, where we collated all the terms where $x$ had exponent $k$.

After your answer, I tried to organize it in my own way in the second half of the main body of the post. This is what you mean, isn't it?

Using the box product and letting $M^{(k)}$ denote the $k$-th compound power (i.e. exterior power) of a square matrix $M$, we have
$$(xA+I)^{(k)}=\sum_{p=0}^k x^pA^{(p)}\mathbin{\square} I^{(k-p)}\tag{1}$$
Taking the trace on both sides of (1) with $k=n$ and using the fact that $\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}(A^{(p)}\mathbin{\square}I^{(n-p)})=\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}(A^{(p)})$, we obtain
$$\det(xA+I)=\sum_{p=0}^n x^p\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}(A^{(p)})=1+x\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}(A)+\cdots+x^n\det(A)\tag{2}$$
Note here $\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}(A^{(p)})$ is just the sum of the $p\times p$ principal minor determinants of $A$.
Taking $k=n-1$ in (1) and then applying the Poincaré dual map, you can obtain the formula for the cofactors. For more details see my videos here and here.

Thank you for your answer. However, it is an advanced solution that uses concepts that are new to me, so I guess I did not understand it well enough. I would like to study linear algebra a little more before reviewing.
